vscode pydevd warning: Computing repr of ... was slow
I'm using VSCode for Python and I'm experiencing following warning which I'm unable to suppress:
pydevd warning: Computing repr of slow_repr_instance (SlowRepr) was slow (took 2.00s)
Customize report timeout by setting the `PYDEVD_WARN_SLOW_RESOLVE_TIMEOUT` environment variable to a higher timeout (default is: 0.5s)

I have found several suggestions of how to fix it but nothing seems able to suppress this warning:
pydevd warnings in Visual Studio Code Debug Console
Fix the following: "pydevd warning: Computing repr of <something> was slow (took 0.35s)" in VS CODE
Below is a my launch- and settings.json files as well as an example code for replicating the warning.
Launch.json:
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [{
            "name": "Python: Current File",
            "type": "debugpy",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${file}",
            "console": "integratedTerminal",
            "justMyCode": false,
            "env": {
                "PYDEVD_DISABLE_FILE_VALIDATION": "1",
                "PYDEVD_WARN_SLOW_RESOLVE_TIMEOUT": "2.0"
            }
        }
    ]
}

Settings.json:
{
    "python.envFile": "${workspaceFolder}/.env",
    "terminal.integrated.env.windows": {
        "PYDEVD_WARN_SLOW_RESOLVE_TIMEOUT": "2.0"
    }
}

Please see sample code to replicate the problem:
import time
 
class SlowRepr:
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value
 
    def __repr__(self):
        # Simulate a slow computation by sleeping for a while
        time.sleep(2) # Adjust the sleep duration to trigger the warning
        return f"SlowRepr({self.value})"
 
# Create an instance of SlowRepr
slow_repr_instance = SlowRepr("This is a slow object")
 
# This line will trigger the warning if the repr computation takes longer than the timeout
print(slow_repr_instance)


So did you try to set the value of PYDEVD_WARN_SLOW_RESOLVE_TIMEOUT to something higher than 2, for example to 3 and check that?

yes I've tried all the way up to 10
